# What are the recommended privacy settings for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I hear a lot about the default privacy settings on Facebook being too open and that third parties can get hold of my private information. What can I do to lock down my account so that only the people I explicitly permit can see my photos and personal information short of deleting my account?

Answer (score 3):

When logged into Facebook, choose Account->Privacy Settings.  Select "Friends Only" on the left and apply the settings.  Alternatively, you can choose the "Customize settings" link and further refine your privacy.

[image: Privacy screen]

Once you've made the appropriate changes, visit http://www.reclaimprivacy.org/ (Edit: Dead Link) to have it scan your settings and make sure you have everything set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Read this -> [Recommended facebook privacy settings june 2011](http://www.slideshare.net/USNavySocialMedia/recommended-facebook-privacy-settings-june-2011) (Edit: Content removed)

Does not get more recommended than that after all it is the US Navy Social Media.

Comment: Link is down...