# Can't comment on Facebook friend's page

Tags: facebook, privacy

I have a friend on Facebook. I can see his wall and his profile, and comments on items in his profile. But I cannot comment on those items. Our mutual friends can, though. Is there a privacy setting that makes it impossible for some friends to post on your items but not others? How do you configure this?

(It's been like this for at least a month, so it's not due to today's Facebook meltdown.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible per person without lists. Here's how he did it, if you want to do it back.

Account (drop down menu at top right) - Privacy - Customize Settings - scroll down - Pick what you want, e.g. "Can see Wall posts by friends"  - Customize - type the first few letters of the name in the not bit, select it and Ok. You can check this by viewing as that person, there won't be a box where the normal post to wall box is.

Answer (score 0):

see

[List based privacy setting in Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/list-based-privacy-setting-in-facebook)

and

[What are the recommended privacy settings for Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/759/what-are-the-recommended-privacy-settings-for-facebook)

These should point you in the right direction to make any combination of settings with Lists.